# Getting undefined from puppeeter evaluate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, puppeteer

When I run this -->

```
let uiElement = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div[class=unf-emptystate-img]').innerHTML)
    console.log(uiElement)
```

I get the correct value

```
<img alt="Waduh, tujuanmu nggak ada!" src="https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/assets-unify/img/il-error-not-found.png">
```

But when I try to use

```
    let uiElement = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div[class=unf-emptystate-img]'))
console.log(uiElement.innerHTML)
```

I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

How do I get `uiElement.innerHTML` without calling the `innerHTML` function inside the evaluate function?

Answer (score 2):

if you use `page.$()`, you can access the `innerHTML`, see this example:

```
const date = await page.$('div[class=unf-emptystate-img]');

console.log(await (await date.getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue());
```

or see this complete example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 250 // slow down by 250ms
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/');

    const date = await page.$('.lead');

    console.log(await (await date.getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue());

})();
```